# Bash Script looking for string in parameter to set a variable

Tags: bash, switch-statement, lookup, glob

I'm quite new to linux, not so much in programing language.
I'm looking for a way to set a variable (var2) to a given value depending on matching the last 3 Bytes of a MAc Adress in var1

Here's an example :

```
var1="AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF"
```

here is my "lookup table" base on the 3 last values of the mac adress"

```
DD:EE:FF > var2="Home"
AB:CD:EF > var2="Garage"
FE:DC:GH > var2="Bedroom1"
... (Max 20)
```

Important thing : The "lookup table" needs to be "readable" because it needs to be easily configurable. I would have used very ugly IF statements otherwise. :-)

Thanks to all the people who will take the time to help me on this.

Comment: Did you actually do any research or try anything out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you need is a `case` statement.

```sh
case $var1 in
 *:DD:EE:FF) var2="Home";;
 *:AB:CD:EF) var2="Garage";;
 *:FE:DC:GH) var2="Bedroom1";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the table (referred to as `table.txt` below):

```
DD:EE:FF Home
AB:CD:EF Garage
FE:DC:GH Bedroom1
```

Then this works:

```
SUFF=$(echo $1 | cut -d ':' -f4-)
echo $SUFF
RES=$(grep ^$SUFF table.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
echo $RES
```

example:

```
> ./run.sh AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
DD:EE:FF
Home
```

I think you'll be able to adjust it for your script from here.

Comment: Thanks, but the solution proposed by triplee is a bit mor user friendly for my usecase.
But I'll keep this solution in mind. Have a great day.

Comment: @DrKamp : From the viewpoint of programming, the solution by triplee is of course elegant, but you also said that you want to keep the table easily modifyiable. I tend to **not** put those data into the code which also uses it, because when editing it, it is too easy to erroneously also modify something in the program. Only for this reason, I would keep the configuration data (MAC address patterns) in a separate file.